# Error when installing gulp on windows 7 using msysGit

Tags: command-line, gulp, msysgit

I'm trying to install gulp using [this tut](http://travismaynard.com/writing/getting-started-with-gulp) and I got the following error. I'm not really sure why, maybe something with my directory choice? I'm using [msysGit](https://msysgit.github.io/).

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'c:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'init' ]
2 info using npm@2.6.0
3 info using node@v0.12.0
4 silly package data undefined
5 info init written successfully
6 verbose stack Error: Invalid name: "sudo npm install -g gulp"
6 verbose stack     at ensureValidName (c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\fixer.js:322:15)
6 verbose stack     at Object.module.exports.fixNameField (c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\fixer.js:211:5)
6 verbose stack     at c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js:30:38
6 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (native)
6 verbose stack     at normalize (c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js:29:15)
6 verbose stack     at final (c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:367:33)
6 verbose stack     at then (c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:126:33)
6 verbose stack     at c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:316:48
6 verbose stack     at evalmachine.<anonymous>:265:20
6 verbose stack     at OpenReq.Req.done (c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:141:5)
7 verbose cwd c:\workstuff
8 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
9 error argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "init"
10 error node v0.12.0
11 error npm  v2.6.0
12 error Invalid name: "sudo npm install -g gulp"
13 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
13 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
14 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: What command did you run?

Comment: @Heikki sudo npm install -g gulp. I changed the directory from the default `~` to c:\workstuff by doing `cd c:\workstuff`

Comment: In tutorial there's `npm init` step before that. It creates package.json file. What does it look like?

Comment: @Heikki Hmm okay it worked when I did `npm init`. I got a bunch of these, do you know what it means?: `npm WARN deprecation in upcoming versions of npm. use the config setting engine-strict instead`

Comment: Just a warning. http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5